# User with 39 Reputation is Shown in Suggested Edit Review Page

Tags: discussion

Following user have 39 Reputations against his name and he is allowed to Suggested Edit Reviews as it can be seen from the image below:

User Details: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3342638/shubhankar

[image]

Is this some sort of bug. Or that user is allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always review [suggested edits to your own posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5290547).

Comment: Ohh I see. Means he is reviewing his own post. Thanks :) I will accept it after 8 mins